# import and merge dataset all in one step via iterative function?

Tags: r, import, merge, dataset

These are the datasets I'm working on.

[image]

Since the P-ones have the following structure

```
# A tibble: 25 x 5
   ID    GR    SES   COND    `LPP2(1000-1500).POz`
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>                   <dbl>
 1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 7.91 
 2 04    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 1.07 
 3 06    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 0.742
 4 07    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 4.49 
 5 08    RP    V     NEG-CTR                -2.43 
 6 09    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 0.649
 7 10    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 1.10 
 8 11    RP    V     NEG-CTR                -2.07 
 9 12    RP    V     NEG-CTR                10.9  
10 13    RP    V     NEG-CTR                 5.17
```

While the V-ones have this following ones, with a more extended number of coulmns:

```
> `RP-V-NEG-CTR`
# A tibble: 25 x 16
   ID    GR    SES   COND    `P3(400-450).FCz` `P3(400-450).Cz` `P3(400-450).Pz` `LPPearly(500-700)~
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>
 1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR           -11.6              -5.17            11.9             -11.8   
 2 04    RP    V     NEG-CTR            -0.314             2.23            15.1              -4.02  
 3 06    RP    V     NEG-CTR            -0.214            -1.30             3.14              4.47  
 4 07    RP    V     NEG-CTR            -2.83              2.19            13.7              -0.884 
 5 08    RP    V     NEG-CTR             4.24              2.45             7.48              1.15  
 6 09    RP    V     NEG-CTR             9.57             13.7             23.4              13.3   
 7 10    RP    V     NEG-CTR            -6.13             -4.13             6.27              0.0229
 8 11    RP    V     NEG-CTR             0.529             5.43            13.0               1.90  
 9 12    RP    V     NEG-CTR            -7.74             -2.41            15.8              -8.08  
10 13    RP    V     NEG-CTR             1.27              3.48             9.94              1.75  
# ... with 15 more rows, and 8 more variables: LPPearly(500-700).Cz <dbl>,
#   LPPearly(500-700).Pz <dbl>, LPP1(500-1000).FCz <dbl>, LPP1(500-1000).Cz <dbl>,
#   LPP1(500-1000).Pz <dbl>, LPP2(1000-1500).FCz <dbl>, LPP2(1000-1500).Cz <dbl>,
#   LPP2(1000-1500).Pz <dbl>
>
```

I've used the followinf procedure for importing and merging them together:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xls")
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  assign(gsub("\\.xls", "", files[i]), readxl::read_xls(files[i]))
}

data <- `RP-V-NEG-CTR` %>% 
  add_row(`RP-V-NEG-NOC`) %>% 
  add_row(`RP-V-NEU-NOC`)%>% 
  arrange(ID)
  
data1 <- `RP-POz-NEG-CTR` %>% 
  add_row(`RP-POz-NEG-NOC`) %>% 
  add_row(`RP-POz-NEU-NOC`)%>% 
  arrange(ID)

data <- merge(data, data1, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND'))
```

Since trying by this following code I've obtain a non-matched merged dataset:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '^RP.*\\.xls$') 
> data <- purrr::map_df(filenames, readxl::read_excel)
```

Like this:

[image]

In the case I would ike to import already merged in a proper way, what am I suppsed to do/adjust?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `files` have both 'V' and 'POz' data.  Sorry, I am trying to understand the concept as you are also `assign`ing to create multiple objects in the global env

Comment: No they don't. Or better all do have in common V but not POz, which is shared just by the P datasets. Maybe this would make clear you r doubt. But actually this is more due to the scarce knowledge I have of these functions. Maybe there will be another solution with pipe operator, but I do not have any knowledge about it

Comment: My understandins in the solution below is that there is a corresponding 'V' for a 'P', thus, read the files separately in `map2` and then do a `join`

Comment: If that is not the one you wanted, I will delete my post

Comment: I'll check. Just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we need `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
filesv <- list.files(pattern = 'RP-V-.*\\.xls', full.names = TRUE)
filesp <- list.files(pattern = 'RP-P-.*\\.xls', full.names = TRUE)
nm1 <- str_c(str_remove(basename(filesv), "\\.xls"), 
             str_remove(basename(filesp), "\\.xls"), sep="_")
out <- map2(filesv, filesp, ~ {
           vdat <- readxl::read_excel(.x)
           pdat <- readxl::read_excel(.y)
           inner_join(vdat, pdat, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND'))
  }) %>%
    setNames(nm1) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

---

Or if we don't need the 'grp' column

```
out <- map2_dfr(filesv, filesp, ~ {
           vdat <- readxl::read_excel(.x)
           pdat <- readxl::read_excel(.y)
           inner_join(vdat, pdat, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND'))
  })
```

Comment: it turns me this error `Error: unexpected ',' in:
"  pdat <- readxl::read_excel(.y)
  inner_join(vdat, pdat, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND')),"`

Comment: @mały_statystyczny sorry, a missing `}`.  Updated

Comment: It worked, but is that needed the .id = grp  in the code? Since it creates a column at the beginning of the dataset.

Comment: @mały_statystyczny it is just an identifier column for the files.  If we are using a named vector, then it will change it to the file name.  Here, it is 1, 2, 3..

Comment: Ok. is possible to remove it. I mean just modifying your code?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny If you don't specify the `.id` it will not be created.  I modified the code to have the file names concatenated as grp column.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again ;)